# I need to split an array in 5 and print repetions in each

Tags: c, arrays

The assignment i have is asking to split an array of 1440 sorted elements in C. We sorted the elements in the previous question. I have got it to work but i was wondering is there a more elegant way of doing it as mine seems to be over thinking it. We are only in week 5 so i can not use anything do advanced at this stage. My code only has the first two loops of the array but i will do the same for the next 3. 
Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    //Open saved .txt file with windspeed values in it for reading
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\niall\\Desktop\\question2.txt","r"); 
    //Intialized varaibles
    double array[MAX];
    int i, x, j, count;
    //Load values from file into an array
    for (i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &array[i]);
    }
    double prev = array[0];
    count = 1;
    printf("\tNumber of times each value is repeated for the first set of values\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i <288; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == prev) 
            count++;
        else
        {
            printf("%.4lf= %d\t", prev, count);

            prev  = array[i];
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    // Printing the last element
    printf("%.4lf= %d\n\n", prev, count);

    prev  = array[288];
    count = 1;

    printf("\tNumber of times each value is repeated for the second set of values\n\n");
    for (i = 288; i <576; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == prev) 
            count++;
        else
        {
            printf("%.4lf= %d\t", prev, count);

            prev  = array[i];
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    // Printing the last element
    printf("%.4lf= %d", prev, count);
}
```

Comment: If the code works, this is off topic here. If you want a review you should post in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to read [their how-to-ask page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first

Comment: You must check that `fp != NULL`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I'll move it.

Answer (score 0):

Your program needs a function like:

```
int nThArrayPrint(double prev, int count, int i, double *array) {
    int minIndex = MAX*i;
    int maxIndex = minIndex + MAX;
    for (i = minIndex; i <maxIndex; i++) {
        if (array[i] == prev) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            prev = array[i];
            count = 1;
            printf("%.4lf= %d\t", prev, count);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

and the program will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VALUE_COUNT 1440
#define MAX 288

int nThArrayPrint(double prev, int count, int i, double *array) {
    int minIndex = MAX*i;
    int maxIndex = minIndex + MAX;
    for (i = minIndex; i <maxIndex; i++) {
        if (array[i] == prev) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            prev = array[i];
            count = 1;
            printf("%.4lf= %d\t", prev, count);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    double array[VALUE_COUNT] = { 0.0, }; // Initializes array to all 0.0s
    double prev = 0.0;
    int i, count;
    FILE *fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");

    if (fp != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < VALUE_COUNT; i++) { //Load values from file into an array
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &array[i]);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        prev = array[0]; // initialize
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            count = 1;
            printf("\tNumber of times each value is repeated for the %dth set of values\n\n", i + 1);
            count = nThArrayPrint(prev, count, i, array);
            prev = array[MAX*i];
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("There was a probem opening the file.");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not claiming that this is an optimal code, but I believe that this will solve the problem you have posted.

---

In my `example.txt` file i gave a sequence of sorted values like `{1.2, 2.3, ...}` of `1441` values.

```
1.2
2.3
3.4
4.5
5.6
6.7
7.8
8.9
10
11.1
12.2
13.3
14.4
15.5
16.6
17.7
18.8
19.9
21
22.1
23.2
24.3
25.4
26.5
27.6
28.7
29.8
30.9
32
33.1
34.2
35.3
36.4
37.5
38.6
39.7
40.8
41.9
43
44.1
45.2
46.3
47.4
48.5
49.6
50.7
51.8
52.9
54
55.1
56.2
57.3
58.4
59.5
60.6
61.7
62.8
63.9
65
66.1
67.2
68.3
69.4
70.5
71.6
72.7
73.8
74.9
76
77.1
78.2
79.3
80.4
81.5
82.6
83.7
84.8
85.9
87
88.1
89.2
90.3
91.4
92.5
93.6
94.7
95.8
96.9
98
99.1
100.2
101.3
102.4
103.5
104.6
105.7
106.8
107.9
109
110.1
111.2
112.3
113.4
114.5
115.6
116.7
117.8
118.9
120
121.1
122.2
123.3
124.4
125.5
126.6
127.7
128.8
129.9
131
132.1
133.2
134.3
135.4
136.5
137.6
138.7
139.8
140.9
142
143.1
144.2
145.3
146.4
147.5
148.6
149.7
150.8
151.9
153
154.1
155.2
156.3
157.4
158.5
159.6
160.7
161.8
162.9
164
165.1
166.2
167.3
168.4
169.5
170.6
171.7
172.8
173.9
175
176.1
177.2
178.3
179.4
180.5
181.6
182.7
183.8
184.9
186
187.1
188.2
189.3
190.4
191.5
192.6
193.7
194.8
195.9
197
198.1
199.2
200.3
201.4
202.5
203.6
204.7
205.8
206.9
208
209.1
210.2
211.3
212.4
213.5
214.6
215.7
216.8
217.9
219
220.1
221.2
222.3
223.4
224.5
225.6
226.7
227.8
228.9
230
231.1
232.2
233.3
234.4
235.5
236.6
237.7
238.8
239.9
241
242.1
243.2
244.3
245.4
246.5
247.6
248.7
249.8
250.9
252
253.1
254.2
255.3
256.4
257.5
258.6
259.7
260.8
261.9
263
264.1
265.2
266.3
267.4
268.5
269.6
270.7
271.8
272.9
274
275.1
276.2
277.3
278.4
279.5
280.6
281.7
282.8
283.9
285
286.1
287.2
288.3
289.4
290.5
291.6
292.7
293.8
294.9
296
297.1
298.2
299.3
300.4
301.5
302.6
303.7
304.8
305.9
307
308.1
309.2
310.3
311.4
312.5
313.6
314.7
315.8
316.9
318
319.1
320.2
321.3
322.4
323.5
324.6
325.7
326.8
327.9
329
330.1
331.2
332.3
333.4
334.5
335.6
336.7
337.8
338.9
340
341.1
342.2
343.3
344.4
345.5
346.6
347.7
348.8
349.9
351
352.1
353.2
354.3
355.4
356.5
357.6
358.7
359.8
360.9
362
363.1
364.2
365.3
366.4
367.5
368.6
369.7
370.8
371.9
373
374.1
375.2
376.3
377.4
378.5
379.6
380.7
381.8
382.9
384
385.1
386.2
387.3
388.4
389.5
390.6
391.7
392.8
393.9
395
396.1
397.2
398.3
399.4
400.5
401.6
402.7
403.8
404.9
406
407.1
408.2
409.3
410.4
411.5
412.6
413.7
414.8
415.9
417
418.1
419.2
420.3
421.4
422.5
423.6
424.7
425.8
426.9
428
429.1
430.2
431.3
432.4
433.5
434.6
435.7
436.8
437.9
439
440.1
441.2
442.3
443.4
444.5
445.6
446.7
447.8
448.9
450
451.1
452.2
453.3
454.4
455.5
456.6
457.7
458.8
459.9
461
462.1
463.2
464.3
465.4
466.5
467.6
468.7
469.8
470.9
472
473.1
474.2
475.3
476.4
477.5
478.6
479.7
480.8
481.9
483
484.1
485.2
486.3
487.4
488.5
489.6
490.7
491.8
492.9
494
495.1
496.2
497.3
498.4
499.5
500.6
501.7
502.8
503.9
505
506.1
507.2
508.3
509.4
510.5
511.6
512.7
513.8
514.9
516
517.1
518.2
519.3
520.4
521.5
522.6
523.7
524.8
525.9
527
528.1
529.2
530.3
531.4
532.5
533.6
534.7
535.8
536.9
538
539.1
540.2
541.3
542.4
543.5
544.6
545.7
546.8
547.9
549
550.1
551.2
552.3
553.4
554.5
555.6
556.7
557.8
558.9
560
561.1
562.2
563.3
564.4
565.5
566.6
567.7
568.8
569.9
571
572.1
573.2
574.3
575.4
576.5
577.6
578.7
579.8
580.9
582
583.1
584.2
585.3
586.4
587.5
588.6
589.7
590.8
591.9
593
594.1
595.2
596.3
597.4
598.5
599.6
600.7
601.8
602.9
604
605.1
606.2
607.3
608.4
609.5
610.6
611.7
612.8
613.9
615
616.1
617.2
618.3
619.4
620.5
621.6
622.7
623.8
624.9
626
627.1
628.2
629.3
630.4
631.5
632.6
633.7
634.8
635.9
637
638.1
639.2
640.3
641.4
642.5
643.6
644.7
645.8
646.9
648
649.1
650.2
651.3
652.4
653.5
654.6
655.7
656.8
657.9
659
660.1
661.2
662.3
663.4
664.5
665.6
666.7
667.8
668.9
670
671.1
672.2
673.3
674.4
675.5
676.6
677.7
678.8
679.9
681
682.1
683.2
684.3
685.4
686.5
687.6
688.7
689.8
690.9
692
693.1
694.2
695.3
696.4
697.5
698.6
699.7
700.8
701.9
703
704.1
705.2
706.3
707.4
708.5
709.6
710.7
711.8
712.9
714
715.1
716.2
717.3
718.4
719.5
720.6
721.7
722.8
723.9
725
726.1
727.2
728.3
729.4
730.5
731.6
732.7
733.8
734.9
736
737.1
738.2
739.3
740.4
741.5
742.6
743.7
744.8
745.9
747
748.1
749.2
750.3
751.4
752.5
753.6
754.7
755.8
756.9
758
759.1
760.2
761.3
762.4
763.5
764.6
765.7
766.8
767.9
769
770.1
771.2
772.3
773.4
774.5
775.6
776.7
777.8
778.9
780
781.1
782.2
783.3
784.4
785.5
786.6
787.7
788.8
789.9
791
792.1
793.2
794.3
795.4
796.5
797.6
798.7
799.8
800.9
802
803.1
804.2
805.3
806.4
807.5
808.6
809.7
810.8
811.9
813
814.1
815.2
816.3
817.4
818.5
819.6
820.7
821.8
822.9
824
825.1
826.2
827.3
828.4
829.5
830.6
831.7
832.8
833.9
835
836.1
837.2
838.3
839.4
840.5
841.6
842.7
843.8
844.9
846
847.1
848.2
849.3
850.4
851.5
852.6
853.7
854.8
855.9
857
858.1
859.2
860.3
861.4
862.5
863.6
864.7
865.8
866.9
868
869.1
870.2
871.3
872.4
873.5
874.6
875.7
876.8
877.9
879
880.1
881.2
882.3
883.4
884.5
885.6
886.7
887.8
888.9
890
891.1
892.2
893.3
894.4
895.5
896.6
897.7
898.8
899.9
901
902.1
903.2
904.3
905.4
906.5
907.6
908.7
909.8
910.9
912
913.1
914.2
915.3
916.4
917.5
918.6
919.7
920.8
921.9
923
924.1
925.2
926.3
927.4
928.5
929.6
930.7
931.8
932.9
934
935.1
936.2
937.3
938.4
939.5
940.6
941.7
942.8
943.9
945
946.1
947.2
948.3
949.4
950.5
951.6
952.7
953.8
954.9
956
957.1
958.2
959.3
960.4
961.5
962.6
963.7
964.8
965.9
967
968.1
969.2
970.3
971.4
972.5
973.6
974.7
975.8
976.9
978
979.1
980.2
981.3
982.4
983.5
984.6
985.7
986.8
987.9
989
990.1
991.2
992.3
993.4
994.5
995.6
996.7
997.8
998.9
1000
1001.1
1002.2
1003.3
1004.4
1005.5
1006.6
1007.7
1008.8
1009.9
1011
1012.1
1013.2
1014.3
1015.4
1016.5
1017.6
1018.7
1019.8
1020.9
1022
1023.1
1024.2
1025.3
1026.4
1027.5
1028.6
1029.7
1030.8
1031.9
1033
1034.1
1035.2
1036.3
1037.4
1038.5
1039.6
1040.7
1041.8
1042.9
1044
1045.1
1046.2
1047.3
1048.4
1049.5
1050.6
1051.7
1052.8
1053.9
1055
1056.1
1057.2
1058.3
1059.4
1060.5
1061.6
1062.7
1063.8
1064.9
1066
1067.1
1068.2
1069.3
1070.4
1071.5
1072.6
1073.7
1074.8
1075.9
1077
1078.1
1079.2
1080.3
1081.4
1082.5
1083.6
1084.7
1085.8
1086.9
1088
1089.1
1090.2
1091.3
1092.4
1093.5
1094.6
1095.7
1096.8
1097.9
1099
1100.1
1101.2
1102.3
1103.4
1104.5
1105.6
1106.7
1107.8
1108.9
1110
1111.1
1112.2
1113.3
1114.4
1115.5
1116.6
1117.7
1118.8
1119.9
1121
1122.1
1123.2
1124.3
1125.4
1126.5
1127.6
1128.7
1129.8
1130.9
1132
1133.1
1134.2
1135.3
1136.4
1137.5
1138.6
1139.7
1140.8
1141.9
1143
1144.1
1145.2
1146.3
1147.4
1148.5
1149.6
1150.7
1151.8
1152.9
1154
1155.1
1156.2
1157.3
1158.4
1159.5
1160.6
1161.7
1162.8
1163.9
1165
1166.1
1167.2
1168.3
1169.4
1170.5
1171.6
1172.7
1173.8
1174.9
1176
1177.1
1178.2
1179.3
1180.4
1181.5
1182.6
1183.7
1184.8
1185.9
1187
1188.1
1189.2
1190.3
1191.4
1192.5
1193.6
1194.7
1195.8
1196.9
1198
1199.1
1200.2
1201.3
1202.4
1203.5
1204.6
1205.7
1206.8
1207.9
1209
1210.1
1211.2
1212.3
1213.4
1214.5
1215.6
1216.7
1217.8
1218.9
1220
1221.1
1222.2
1223.3
1224.4
1225.5
1226.6
1227.7
1228.8
1229.9
1231
1232.1
1233.2
1234.3
1235.4
1236.5
1237.6
1238.7
1239.8
1240.9
1242
1243.1
1244.2
1245.3
1246.4
1247.5
1248.6
1249.7
1250.8
1251.9
1253
1254.1
1255.2
1256.3
1257.4
1258.5
1259.6
1260.7
1261.8
1262.9
1264
1265.1
1266.2
1267.3
1268.4
1269.5
1270.6
1271.7
1272.8
1273.9
1275
1276.1
1277.2
1278.3
1279.4
1280.5
1281.6
1282.7
1283.8
1284.9
1286
1287.1
1288.2
1289.3
1290.4
1291.5
1292.6
1293.7
1294.8
1295.9
1297
1298.1
1299.2
1300.3
1301.4
1302.5
1303.6
1304.7
1305.8
1306.9
1308
1309.1
1310.2
1311.3
1312.4
1313.5
1314.6
1315.7
1316.8
1317.9
1319
1320.1
1321.2
1322.3
1323.4
1324.5
1325.6
1326.7
1327.8
1328.9
1330
1331.1
1332.2
1333.3
1334.4
1335.5
1336.6
1337.7
1338.8
1339.9
1341
1342.1
1343.2
1344.3
1345.4
1346.5
1347.6
1348.7
1349.8
1350.9
1352
1353.1
1354.2
1355.3
1356.4
1357.5
1358.6
1359.7
1360.8
1361.9
1363
1364.1
1365.2
1366.3
1367.4
1368.5
1369.6
1370.7
1371.8
1372.9
1374
1375.1
1376.2
1377.3
1378.4
1379.5
1380.6
1381.7
1382.8
1383.9
1385
1386.1
1387.2
1388.3
1389.4
1390.5
1391.6
1392.7
1393.8
1394.9
1396
1397.1
1398.2
1399.3
1400.4
1401.5
1402.6
1403.7
1404.8
1405.9
1407
1408.1
1409.2
1410.3
1411.4
1412.5
1413.6
1414.7
1415.8
1416.9
1418
1419.1
1420.2
1421.3
1422.4
1423.5
1424.6
1425.7
1426.8
1427.9
1429
1430.1
1431.2
1432.3
1433.4
1434.5
1435.6
1436.7
1437.8
1438.9
1440
1441.1
1442.2
1443.3
1444.4
1445.5
1446.6
1447.7
1448.8
1449.9
1451
1452.1
1453.2
1454.3
1455.4
1456.5
1457.6
1458.7
1459.8
1460.9
1462
1463.1
1464.2
1465.3
1466.4
1467.5
1468.6
1469.7
1470.8
1471.9
1473
1474.1
1475.2
1476.3
1477.4
1478.5
1479.6
1480.7
1481.8
1482.9
1484
1485.1
1486.2
1487.3
1488.4
1489.5
1490.6
1491.7
1492.8
1493.9
1495
1496.1
1497.2
1498.3
1499.4
1500.5
1501.6
1502.7
1503.8
1504.9
1506
1507.1
1508.2
1509.3
1510.4
1511.5
1512.6
1513.7
1514.8
1515.9
1517
1518.1
1519.2
1520.3
1521.4
1522.5
1523.6
1524.7
1525.8
1526.9
1528
1529.1
1530.2
1531.3
1532.4
1533.5
1534.6
1535.7
1536.8
1537.9
1539
1540.1
1541.2
1542.3
1543.4
1544.5
1545.6
1546.7
1547.8
1548.9
1550
1551.1
1552.2
1553.3
1554.4
1555.5
1556.6
1557.7
1558.8
1559.9
1561
1562.1
1563.2
1564.3
1565.4
1566.5
1567.6
1568.7
1569.8
1570.9
1572
1573.1
1574.2
1575.3
1576.4
1577.5
1578.6
1579.7
1580.8
1581.9
1583
1584.1
1585.2
```

And it gave me an output shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Please comment if something else is expected.

Edit:

In response to comment

1. I have removed this line from the modified code:

   ```
           printf("%.4lf= %d\n\n", prev, count);
   ```
2. Modified the function above as well.

Comment: That code looks great. Its nearly perfect but it seems to have a problem with the last value in each block of the array. The first value in each set is also the last value in each set

Comment: Anyone an idea on how to fix this new code. I can not see anything obvious.

Comment: Can you share at least a part of the content of Question2.txt in your question?

Comment: You see the first and last value in each part of what you printed. That is not right is it

Comment: @niallo27, i dont understand what you are refering to. Can you be more specific...

Comment: You see at the end of your 4th set of values it goes from 1266.2 to 951.6 and then the next series starts with 951.6 again. 951.6 should not be there should it

Comment: @niallo27, I have updated the code and updated the reasoning as well. Forgot to put up a comment over here. Please test and let me know if something else needs changing.